# Two Languages Displayed in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The languages that I have in my PC just English and Arabic, everything is desplayed in either  except VBA I see another language I am not sure it is Chinese or what

Languages in Office are english and arabic where english on top, same for windows, I just need english

[image]

[image]

Comment: The VBE is a non-Unicode program and hence uses the specified system locale (Language for non-Unicode programs). You can check and change that setting by opening the Settings app and following these options: Time & language -> Language & region > Administrative language settings. In the window that opens go to the "Administrative" tab. Here you should see the currently specified language for non-Unicode programs and change it by clicking the button "Change system locale".

Comment: Thanks a lot although it was English united kingdom I changed it to English united states and checked Unicode and it worked thanks a lot